# How to connect to server using SOCKS5 protocol from JavaScript in browser?

Tags: javascript, socks

How I may connect to server using SOCKS5 protocol from my JavaScript code in browser?
I've found [socks5-https-client](https://github.com/mattcg/socks5-https-client) library but this is only for Node.js, not for browser JS.
My goal is establish secure connection for SIP UDP or TCP protocol in SIP client in browser, but unfortunately SIP server behind proxy that offer SOCKS5 for SIP connections.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

There are no APIs provided to JS by the browser that allow making either arbitrary network connections or SOCKS connections.